# How to gently stop/pause an animation in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, css-animations

I am trying to create a personal webpage. In this website I will 4 circles that move in a circular path infinitely. If I ever hover my cursor over one of the circles, I want all of the circles to gently come to a stop, and have the one I am hovering over move into the center of the circle and increase in size. I have an idea on how to do the latter, but my main issue is how I can get a CSS animation come to a gentle stop and not a sudden halt, kind of like ease transition that comes to a stop, except in a much shorter period of time.

I have tried researching quite a bit but the only thing I come across is the `animation-play-state` property. However, this property can only bring the animation to a complete `pause`, which is not what I want. I cannot use the `transition` property on `animation-play-state` even if I wanted to because `transition` only works if there are numerical values that can be altered as time pass for the transition (like `opacity` going from 0.5 to 0.9 in .1 increments based on transition time as opposed to `visibility` being either just `hidden` or `visible`).

I am open to the idea of needing to JS if necessary (I am just getting into web development). However, I would prefer if there are any answers that compose of just CSS or vanilla JS as I want to get a strong base in CSS and JS before moving on to frameworks.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-play-and-pause-css-animations-with-css-custom-properties/

Comment: I cam across this website, but it only seems to inform on completely stopping and starting the animation. I would like to make it so that the animation slows down to a stop, kind of like easing into a stop.

Comment: Check this article at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationstart_event), it may assist as well.